# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80 when using Post request with axios

Tags: node.js, axios

```
 Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:80
at Object._errnoException (util.js:1022:11)
at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1044:20)
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1198:14)
```

code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 80,
I am getting the above error when i am trying to upload a video file to youtube using axios backend server is running on my system and i am getting this error ehen the file is being uploaded from my server to youtube

Comment: Show us some code with what you tried so far

Comment: A piece of code would help a lot. It simply just there is no server handle localhost:80

Comment: thank u guys i was passing the wrong url instead of writing baseURL i was writing baseURl